# AJAX call via IE fails on site with integrated security

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, iis, authentication, windows-authentication

I have a site which uses integrated windows authentication to prevent unauthorized access. Calling the same page through AJAX fails in IE (other browsers ok) with a status code of 12015 (login failed). It appears that IE is not passing the login credentials to the XMLHttpRequest object. Anyone else seen this?

George

Answer (score 1):

I observed the 12015 error status when I used an abbreviated domain name, i.e. the hostname instead of fully qualified domain name, EdgeServer01 vs. EdgeServer01.contoso.com.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ajax jQuery could be an option for you? 
That should handle the 'auth', etc... for all browsers.

```
 $.ajax(strURL, {
        type: 'POST',
        data: { value1: 'value', value2: 'value2' },
        success: function (resp) {
            // do something 
        },
        error: function() {  }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, no jQuery is not of interest. The question was to confirm behavior really.